# rpmbuild failure: error: Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found:

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Not sure if this is the right place to post the question. I am trying to create rpm's for my project, this is the first time I am writing a spec file. When I am building the spec the file with the command

> rpmbuild -ba name.spec

```
error: Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found:
   etc/gluster-object/account-server/1.conf
   etc/gluster-object/cert.crt
   etc/gluster-object/cert.key
   etc/gluster-object/container-server/1.conf
   etc/gluster-object/fs.conf
   etc/gluster-object/gluster-object.conf
   etc/gluster-object/object-server/1.conf
   etc/gluster-object/proxy-server.conf
```

Please find the link ( http://pastie.org/2426321 ) to spec file. Any help on this is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you put the files into `%{_conf_dir}/gluster-object`, but tell `rpmbuild` to include the files from `%{_conf_dir}/%{_obj_dir}/*`. That seems to be a difference.

```
%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
%{_conf_dir}/gluster-object/*
```

would be the way to go.

Comment: I have declared

%define _obj_dir gluster-object. 

I gave it a try by changing the name. But still the same error.

Comment: 1. Are there other files which are recognized, or is the above list complete concerning created files? 2. What is `%{_conf_dir}`? Here on OpenSUSE, I have `%{_sysconfdir}`. Did you manually set it? Is there an additional message claiming that files could not be found?

Comment: I manually set it...Actually I figured out the problem, I had to include the name of the package after %files in the spec file.. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh, a subpackage :-) A complete spec file would have been helpful here. Have fun with RPM :-)